# How can I stop the UITableView over scroll at the top and bottom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am using a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCells` and I want to stop the "over" scroll that you get at the top and bottom of the list, The bit where you can pull down on the very top cell to show the background (sometimes used to refresh) Is there anyway to just make the top edge of the cell the "absolute top"? so the view only ever shows just the cells?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollview, it should suffice to just set the 'bounces' property to NO.

Edit: you probably need to set'alwaysBounceVertical' to NO, too...

Comment: Much appreciated, [[self tableView] setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO]; on its own did not work, but [[self tableView] setBounces:NO]; did, thank you Sir.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this code to solve your Problem

```
self.objBackTableView.bounces = NO;
```

And used Below code to if data is fit on screen than its not scroll

```
self.objBackTableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
```

Comment: Welcome SURESH SANKE

Answer (score 8):

You can set the tableview bounces property to NO.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4.2:

It's not scroll at all:

```
tableView.bounces = false
```

It's not scroll if there is enough space for cells:

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = false
```

Hope to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

**Interface builder**

1. Select table view in *Document Outline* on left side
2. Navigate to *View Inspector* on right side
3. Uncheck Bounce Vertically

[image]