# Disable Pull-To-Refresh

Tags: ios, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

I have a static group of cells, a few groups actually, and for some reason the pull to refresh function is enabled, I can't figure out where, at least in Xcode Interface builder an option is to disable that. I assume I'll have to do it programmatically.

Does anyone know how this needs to be done in Swift?

Comment: Hope this help:
[Disable Pull To Refresh in TableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16937849/10775602)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're using `UITableViewController`, it should be something as simple as

```
self.refreshControl = nil
```

Comment: DUH. I thought I tried that. Xcode UI said "The default value of this property is nil" but when I did it, it worked. So that's confusing. Thank you though!

Comment: I'll accept the answer when stack overflow decides it's time lol

Comment: I tried this in the initWithStyle, but it looked like preventing the navigation bar to appear; I moved it to the viewDidLoad, AFTER un-hiding the navigation bar, and it worked well, without collateral effects. Up-voted anyway.

Answer (score 4):

In storyboard, go to your Attributes Inspector for your View Controller and disable it there where it says 'Refreshing':

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For swift 4 you can using

```
 self.yourTableView.refreshControl = nil
```