# Stop overscroll UITableView only at the top?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview

There is similar question [Stop UITableView over scroll at top & bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937764/stop-uitableview-over-scroll-at-top-bottom), but I need slighty different functionality. I want my table so that it can be overscrolled at the bottom, but cannot be overscrolled at the top.
As I understood,

```
tableView.bounces = false
```

Allows to disable overscrolling at both top and bottom, however, I need disabling this only at the top. Like

```
tableView.bouncesAtTheTop = false
tableView.bouncesAtTheBottom = true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by changing the `bounce` property in `scrollViewDidScroll` of the tableView (you need to be the delegate of the tableView)

Have a property for the lastY:

```
var lastY: CGFloat = 0.0
```

Set initial bounce to false in `viewDidLoad`:

```
tableView.bounces = false
```

and:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let currentBottomY = scrollView.frame.size.height + currentY
    if currentY > lastY {
        //"scrolling down"
        tableView.bounces = true
    } else {
        //"scrolling up"
        // Check that we are not in bottom bounce
        if currentBottomY < scrollView.contentSize.height + scrollView.contentInset.bottom {
            tableView.bounces = false
        }
    }
    lastY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: You can just check if `scrollView.contentOffset.y` is smaller than 0.0. And if it is, just set it to 0.0. This way the scrollView won't be able to overscroll only in "up" direction

Answer (score 12):

For Swift 2.2, Use

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == self.tableView {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
        }
    }
}
```

For Objective C

```
    -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}
```